# Can we set a custom delegate object for NSURLSessionTaskDelegate

Tags: nsurlsession

In NSURLSession, we add tasks to a session by methods like

- dataTaskWithRequest:
- dataTaskWithRequest:completionHandler:

As far as I understand, if we use the one without completionHandler or use nil for completionHandler, self will be used automatically as the delegate and we can expect delegate methods to be called. Do I understand correctly?

Is there possible to specify different delegate (other than self ) for each task?

I checked sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue and I think that delegate is a NSURLSessionDelegate.

Comment: With more investigation, it seems that sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue is the way to set delegate for all protocols including NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate and NSURLSessionDataDelegate

Answer (score 2):

Answer my own question. We actually can use sessionWithConfiguration:delegate:delegateQueue to setup delegate. According to [apple's URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/NSURLSessionConcepts/NSURLSessionConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i-CH2-SW1),

> if you need to handle authentication or caching in a nondefault
>   manner, you must provide a delegate that conforms to the session
>   delegate protocol, one or more task delegate protocols, or some
>   combination of these protocols. This delegate serves many purposes